# Meteor - Serverside copy files from FS.Collection

Tags: node.js, bash, mongodb, meteor, collections

I'm using a bash script to compile a Unity assetbundle. I run it on a server using an interval I setup in Meteor which I run as a server.

Using {{url}} client-side I can get the file url fine. But how can I copy/move or even access the physical file on the server?

I'd like to be able to copy files to my unity project and run my bash script.

Comment: FSCollection.findOne().url() ??

Comment: Yeah but that uses routing and doesnt actually reflect the path on the server, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered I defined a path to a folder when defining the collection. Having looked for it, i found all the files i need.

Apologies for wasting your time.